# Automatically populate html input control with query string parameter's value without using JavaScript

Tags: html, mapping, query-string

Is there a way to populate - automatically and without using JavaScript or any other code - an HTML input control with the Query String parameter's value as long as the parameter's name can be matched to the input control's name?

Thanks

Comment: You need a rendering engine to do this.  If you have a PHP, Rails, or other type of backend you can do this.  You cannot do this in a static website without JavaScript.